# REGEX to replace numbers with String

Tags: java, regex, salesforce

I have a String as below:

((((1 OR 2) AND 3) OR 11) AND 23)

I want to replace numbers with String values.

I am new to regex and unable to figure out how to replace numbers lying within a range.

Comment: Do you want to replace numbers with string value of numbers ?

Comment: no I have other string values will be populated

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code to resolve your problem. My poor regex knowlodge was not enough to resolve by only using regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String temp = "(X)+|";
    String regex = "";
    String text = "((((1 OR 2) AND 3) OR 11) AND 23)";
    Map<String, String> numberToString = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> Integer.valueOf(o2) - Integer.valueOf(o1));

    numberToString.put("3", "THREE");
    numberToString.put("2", "TWO");
    numberToString.put("1", "ONE");
    numberToString.put("11", "ELEVEN");
    numberToString.put("23", "TWENTYTHREE");

    for(String number : numberToString.keySet()){
        regex = regex + temp.replace("X", number);
    }
    regex = regex.substring(0, regex.lastIndexOf('|'));
    Set<String> allMatches = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> Integer.valueOf(o2) - Integer.valueOf(o1));
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
    for (String match : allMatches) {
        if (numberToString.get(match) != null)
            text = text.replaceAll(match, numberToString.get(match));
    }

    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(regex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str.replaceAll(1, "one"); function

Comment: It will not work because 11 will be also replaced with One. 

We want to replace only the exact character given in the key. For eg. 1 should only be replaced with One not 111, 11, 11111 etc.